# Numpy masked arrays - indicating missing values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma

"""This operates as expected with one value masked"""
a = [0., 1., 1.e20, 9.]
error_value = 1.e20
b = ma.masked_values(a, error_value)
print b

"""This does not, all values are masked """
d = [0., 1., 'NA', 9.]
error_value = 'NA'
e = ma.masked_values(d, error_value)
print e
```

How can I use 'nan', 'NA', 'None', or some similar value to indicate missing data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you getting your data from a text file or similar?  If so, I'd suggest using the [`genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) function directly to specify your masked value:

```
In [149]: f = StringIO('0.0, 1.0, NA, 9.0')

In [150]: a = np.genfromtxt(f, delimiter=',', missing_values='NA', usemask=True)

In [151]: a
Out[151]:
masked_array(data = [0.0 1.0 -- 9.0],
             mask = [False False  True False],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

I think the problem in your example is that the python list you're using to initialize the numpy array has heterogeneous types (floats and a string).  The values are coerced to a strings in a numpy array, but the [`masked_values`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_values.html#numpy.ma.masked_values) function uses floating point equality yielding the strange results.

Here's one way to overcome this by creating an array with object dtype:

```
In [152]: d = np.array([0., 1., 'NA', 9.], dtype=object)

In [153]: e = ma.masked_values(d, 'NA')

In [154]: e
Out[154]:
masked_array(data = [0.0 1.0 -- 9.0],
             mask = [False False  True False],
       fill_value = ?)
```

You may prefer the first solution since the result has a float dtype.

Comment: I want to preserve the missing value information in my array (in memory).  My purpose in using a mask is so that the array can be averaged, ignoring the missing values.  As pointed out in the ma docs the purpose of ma is to allow the processing of data with missing or invalid values.  In real data series 'NA', 'None' or similar is ofter used to mark missing values.  Does the "fill_value" option provide any way to accomplish my objective?

Comment: @Dick: Yes, both methods above accomplish what you need.  They both preserve the information that element 3 is missing (the fill_value is not as important if that's all you care about).  For example you can call `a.mean()` or `e.mean()` and see that the result is `3.33`.  Whatever character/string your data series uses for missing values can be used instead of `'NA'` in the examples above.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works, it does force the creation of a copy of the array.

```
a_true = (a == 'NA')

a[a_true] = 1.e20

a = a.astype(float)

print a

error_value = 1.e20

b = ma.masked_values(a, error_value)

print b
```